# Add MS Teams website tab using graph API error

Tags: c#, tabs, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

**Context:**

I am trying to add a new website tab to an existing channel in MS Teams and then get the id of newly-created tab.

**Problem:**

I am able to create new tab but I am getting a "BadRequest" exception from the Graph:

*Message: Value cannot be null. Parameter name: entity*

The interesting part is that the tab is created and visible in MS Teams in the correct team and channel but I cannot get it's id in any way.

**My code:**

```
var tab = await _graphClient.Teams[teamId].Channels[channelId].Tabs.Request().WithMaxRetry(3).AddAsync(
    new TeamsTab
    {
        DisplayName = "New Tab",
        AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            ["teamsApp@odata.bind"] =
                $"{_teamsFactory.GraphV1Endpoint}/appCatalogs/teamsApps/com.microsoft.teamspace.tab.web"
        },
        Configuration = new TeamsTabConfiguration
        {
            EntityId = null,
            WebsiteUrl = $"{_appUrl}/1",
            ContentUrl = $"{_appUrl}/1",
            RemoveUrl = null,

        }
    }
);
```

Like I wrote above, this code works and the tab is created but **GraphServiceClient** throws an exception before the **tab** variable is assigned.

And when I tried to get the tab list in Graph Explorer

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{teamid}/channels/{channelid}/tabs`

I received an error response:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InternalServerError",
        "message": "Failed to execute request.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "a03654e8-37a7-4fbb-8052-6a1b11721234",
            "date": "2020-02-24T15:11:54"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the "solution" though a better name is a workaround for my issue. To make it work I had to set `ODataType` to `null` in `TeamsTabConfiguration`. That's all. The code should look like this:

```
var tab = await _graphClient.Teams[teamId].Channels[channelId].Tabs.Request().WithMaxRetry(3).AddAsync(
new TeamsTab
{
    DisplayName = TabTitle,
    ODataBind = $"{_teamsFactory.GraphV1Endpoint}/appCatalogs/teamsApps/com.microsoft.teamspace.tab.web",
    Configuration = new TeamsTabConfiguration
    {
        ODataType = null,
        EntityId = null,
        WebsiteUrl = $"{_appUrl}/1",
        ContentUrl = $"{_appUrl}/1",
        RemoveUrl = null
    }
});
```

Like I mentioned it is only a workaround. It is labeled as "service bug" on GitHub ([issue#598](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/598))

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to set a value for "EntityId" - basically just a string value to uniquely "name" your tab. It's not the "DisplayName", more a string "id" for the tab.

Comment: I tried this before but it didn't help. EntityId property should be set to null according to MS documentation [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-configuring-builtin-tabs) (section Website tabs)

Comment: oh yeah, I see what you mean - I was thinking of custom app. Have a look here though: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamstab-add?view=graph-rest-1.0 . In the comments in the bottom, it looks like maybe ["teamsApp@odata.bind"] = $"_teamsFactory.GraphV1Endpoint}/appCatalogs/teamsApps/com.microsoft.teamspace.tab.web" should actually be just plain ["teamsApp@odata.bind"] = "com.microsoft.teamspace.tab.web"

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work. I got "Invalid URL format specified in @odata.bind for teamsApp" error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{id}/channels/{id}/tabs
{
  "displayName": "My Contoso Tab",
  "teamsApp@odata.bind" : "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps/06805b9e-77e3-4b93-ac81-525eb87513b8",
  "configuration": {
    "entityId": "2DCA2E6C7A10415CAF6B8AB6661B3154",
    "contentUrl": "https://www.contoso.com/Orders/2DCA2E6C7A10415CAF6B8AB6661B3154/tabView",
    "websiteUrl": "https://www.contoso.com/Orders/2DCA2E6C7A10415CAF6B8AB6661B3154",
    "removeUrl": "https://www.contoso.com/Orders/2DCA2E6C7A10415CAF6B8AB6661B3154/uninstallTab"
  }
}
```

Please take a look at [Add Tab to a channel using Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-configuring-builtin-tabs)

**Edit 1: Could you please check you have appropriate permissions to add the Tab?**

**Edit2: Could you please try below piece of code?**

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var teamsTab = new TeamsTab
{
    DisplayName = "WebsiteTab",
    AdditionalData = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        {"teamsApp@odata.bind","https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/appCatalogs/teamsApps/com.microsoft.teamspace.tab.web"}
    },
    Configuration = new TeamsTabConfiguration
    {
        EntityId = null,
        ContentUrl = "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bots-context",
        RemoveUrl = null,
        WebsiteUrl = "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bots-context"
    }
};

await graphClient.Teams["TeamId"].Channels["ChannelId"].Tabs
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(teamsTab);
```

Comment: I am trying to add **website** tab. According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/teams-configuring-builtin-tabs) teamsAppId is "com.microsoft.teamspace.tab.web" and the entityId property should be set to null.

Comment: It is working when you set the entity id as null, Could you please share more details or repro steps or screen recording would be better for further investigation?

Comment: @Tomasz, Are you still facing this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately yes. I set the entityId property to null (as you can see in the code part i shared in the problem description) and it is working to the point when the tab is created. Then the code throws an exception with the message "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: entity" and I cannot get the id of created tab.

Comment: Please reachout to microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com so we can debug and see the issue.

Comment: @TomaszPrzetacki did you ever come right with this?

Comment: Maybe if you just search for it to get the ID after creation, as you need to swallow the exception.